# Numpy unique with distinct members

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I'm trying to find the unique elements of a N x 2 array irrespective of the order. For example, given the array

```
a = [[1,0],
     [2,5],
     [0,1],
     [1,0]]
```

it would give me back

```
a = [[1,0],
     [2,5]]
```

Currently I'm using an approach with numpy.sort()

```
a = np.unique(np.sort(a, axis=1), axis=0)
```

which gets the job done but I feel like this is an overly complicated way of achieving my goal and possibly slow especially for larger arrays. Are there better, "sort-avoiding" methods?

Comment: Not using numpy methods, a potentially faster than sorting approach would be to use sets

Comment: but wouldn't that require stacking sets into sets? I thought this does not work

Comment: `unique` itself is using sort.  Your approach of first making things consistent across columns looks quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment, I don't think numpy can do this natively.

What you can do is use python `sets` to generate unique objects.

`numpy.unique` doesn't seem to handle sets very well, so an extra conversion step to tuple is needed:

```
np.unique(list(map(tuple, map(set, a))), axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 5]])
```

If you want to recover the indices:

```
_, idx = np.unique(list(map(tuple, map(set, a))), axis=0, return_index=True)

a[idx]
```